# How to fix cordova build error: unsupported class file major version 62

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

i'm getting this error when i run `cordova build android` on my mac.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/ad8kunle/MarasoftBank/platforms/android/repositories.gradle'

* What went wrong:
Could not compile script '/Users/ad8kunle/MarasoftBank/platforms/android/repositories.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 62
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 62
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.decompiled.AsmDecompiler.parseClass(AsmDecompiler.java:81)
```

Any idea on how it can be resolved?

Comment: Hi, to fix this issue, make sure you are on `Java 11` since `Java 18` is not yet supported.